# Series $\sum c_n=s$ , does $nc_n\rightarrow0$?

Tags: calculus

Series $\sum c_n=s$ , does $nc_n\rightarrow0$?

I guess it does, but I don't know how to prove , perhaps, for all convergent series , we will have $$c_n=O(\frac{1}{nf(n)})$$ here $1/f(n)=o(1)$

Answer (score 3):

No it does not.

Consider
$$
c_n = \begin{cases}
\dfrac 1n , & \sqrt n \in \mathbb N^*,\\
\dfrac 1{n^2}, & \sqrt n \notin \mathbb N^*. 
\end{cases}
$$
Then the series converges, but $n c_n$ is either $1/n$ or $1$, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: $c_n=(-1)^{n}\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ gives an example where $|nc_n| \to \infty$.

Comment: Why not post this as an answer?